# How do I add a binding and endpoint that utilizes SSL for a WCF Workflow Service?

Tags: wcf, workflow-foundation, workflow-foundation-4

I have a need to secure my WCF service using SSL.  The problem I'm running into is that this is a WCF Workflow service, and I can't seem to override the default bindings that it sets up behind the scenes.

There must be something that I'm missing in the configuration file, as whatever I do, the binding always comes back as: BasicHttpBinding_IService at address : http://myurl.com/biz/MyService.xamlx

It should be: https://myurl.com/biz/MyService.xamlx.

These are the bindings and endpoint sections:

```
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="basicBinding">
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<services>
  <service name="MyNamespace.MyService">
    <endpoint address="https://myurl.com/biz/MyService.xamlx"
              binding="basicHttpBinding"
              bindingConfiguration="basicBinding"
              contract="IService" />
  </service>
</services>
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

A few things to try:

- change the binding to wsHttpBinding and that will force SSL.
- change clientCredentialType to Certificate.
- use this example and set the httpsGetEnabled to true:

http://blog.adnanmasood.com/2008/07/16/https-with-basichttpbinding-note-to-self/

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I tried these suggestions, and unfortunately none of them worked.  However, I did finally got the solution.  I'll post it as an answer shortly.